# can't redefine value for undefined

Tags: javascript

Does Chrome prohibit changing value for `undefined`? I've just tried:

```
undefined = 3
```

But when then querying `undefined` it gives me `undefined`

PS. I'm not going to redefine it in my code, I'm just wondering why it's not working.

Comment: Its must be in all browser , not only chrome

Comment: `undefined` is not reserved, it is actually a property of the global object, you can change the value depending on the browser, unless you are in strict mode.

Comment: @elclanrs - did you try that?

Comment: @mplungjan: yes, it is not a reserved word; it is an immutable property in ES5+. This will work in current browsers for example: `(function(){var undefined='foo'; return undefined;}())// 'foo'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is correct. Most modern browsers prevent changing the value of `undefined`.

From the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined):

> In modern browsers (JavaScript 1.8.5 / Firefox 4+), undefined is a non-configurable, non-writable property per the ECMAScript 5 specification. Even when this is not the case, avoid overriding it.

So `undefined` is not mutable in modern browsers, even though it is a property of the global object.

Comment: Since what versions and which browsers is this the case?